# Unable to send emails

Tags: gmail

I am getting the following error message when attempting to send emails:

> Error
>   The address "essentialphysicaltherapy.net" in the "To" field was not recognized.
>   Please make sure that all addresses are properly formed.

It has happened to more than one address. Another one that's being bounced is to my Congressman whose address is `defazio.house.gov`. I have double checked his email address and retyped it a number of times with the same result.

I have only tried this from Gmail because Gmail is my only email account.

Comment: The address in your error message isn't a standard email address (*abc@company.com*). Are the email addresses that you're trying to send mail to formatted correctly?

Comment: Also, are all of the email addresses that you can't send to in the same domain (i.e. xxx@abc.com)? Does this only happen from Gmail?

Comment: They are formatted correctly. Another one that's being bounced is to my Congressman who's address is defazio.house.gov. i have doublechecked his email address and retyped it a number of times with the same result. I have only tried this from gmail because gmail is my only email account.

Comment: `defazio.house.gov` might be his web page; what is his email address that you've been trying to send to?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That is his web page. duh. Thanks. As far as the other one goes, that IS their email address. I've tried again and again with the same results.

Comment: Can you clarify -- what do you mean by "the other one?" What is the email address(es) you are sending to?

Comment: The other is: essentialphysicaltherapy.net

Comment: *essentialphysicaltherapy.net* is not a valid email address. It sounds like that's why you're getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you've provided, it appears that you are getting that error message because the addresses you are using -- `essentialphysicaltherapy.net` and `defazio.house.gov` -- are not properly formatted email addresses. A properly formatted email address would look like `abc@company.com`.

For example (these may or may not be real email addresses, but they illustrate standard email address format):

- `help@essentialphysicaltherapy.net`
- `john.doe@essentialphysicaltherapy.net`
- `info@defazio.house.gov`
- `contact@defazio.house.gov`

Visit the web pages that you mentioned and try to find a valid contact email -- then you should avoid getting that error message.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. That's correct, of course. Thank you.